# ARKit – Replicating robot character in Motion Capture RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, maya, realitykit

I'm trying to make a 3d model like robot provided by Apple in Motion Capture example (shown at WWDC 2019) which can mimic me in motion capture ARKit 3.0 by replacing robot character given by Apple.

Desired Solution:

- Is there any special software which Apple used to create `robot.usdz` file? If yes, then please provide details for it?
- How can we convert formats like `.glb`/`.gltf`/`.obj`/`.dae` file to `.usdz` using Apple’s Python based tool without affecting it’s scene graph?
- How can we edit the scene graph of a `.usdz` file in Xcode and successfully save the changes in a .usdz file?

Answer (score 3):

#### Creating your own MoCap model for AR app

- Import or create a character in Autodesk Maya 2024
- Download Apple's [biped robot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/validating_a_model_for_motion_capture) model
- Unbind mesh from skeleton and delete robot mesh
- Bind the skeleton to your character using `Skin`–`Bind Skin` menu
- Export a model as FBX file format
- Convert an exported FBX model into USDZ in Reality Converter

[image]

Load MoCap model in RealityKit:

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    var character: Entity?
    let characterAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        arView.session.delegate = self

        guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.isSupported
        else { fatalError("MoCap is available on A12 & later") }
        
        let config = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.session.run(config)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(characterAnchor)
        
        character = try? Entity.load(named: "character")
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        for anchor in anchors {
            
            guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor
            else { continue }

            let bodyPosition = simd_make_float3(bodyAnchor.transform.columns.3)
            characterAnchor.position = bodyPosition
            characterAnchor.orientation = Transform(matrix: bodyAnchor.transform).rotation

            if let character = character, character.parent == nil {

                characterAnchor.addChild(character)
                characterAnchor.scale = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
            }
        }
    }
}
```